# Don't have a separate page for chat searching

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, chat

Clicking the search link on any page opens a new window/tab with a tiny search box on the left, leaving the rest of the page unused.  Can we get it to show in a little box instead, and open the new window when we submit the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this, but I think we need to get the mechanics of chat search nailed down a bit better first before "oneboxing" it.